How do I change this timer for my Unity Game to work in a minute:second format with only two decimal places after the seconds?
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TMP_Text timerText;
    float timer;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        timerText = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
        timer = 0.0f;
    }
        void Update()
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            float seconds = timer % 60;

            timerText.text = "Timer: " + seconds.ToString();
        }
}

Very new to programming C# scripts and using unity and i'm trying to figure out how to produce a timer for a game for a uni module. I've managed to place the timer in the top left of the camera UI where it follows the player and shows "Time: (time here)" however it is only in seconds with several decimal points after and goes back to zero after reaching sixty. Help much appreciated!

It sounds like you may be looking for help in multiple ways, but let's focus the question on one.  Are you mainly asking how to format the seconds value to a specified number of decimal places?  Have you done any research on formatting a number to a specified number of decimal places in C#?

well so far you only extract seconds. So for starters you also want the according minutes
var minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(timer / 60);

and finally use a ToString with desired formatter string - for instance e.g. N (applies rounding).
And then I'd recommend string interpolation
timerText.text = $"Timer: {minutes}:{seconds:N0}";

for a format like
Timer: 3:15

or accordingly
timerText.text = $"Timer: {minutes}:{seconds:N2}";

for a format like
Timer: 3:15.23

(whether . or , is used as decimal separator depends on the current Culture - alternatively you can go back to using ToString and explicitly pass in CultureInfo.InvariantCulture to always use .)
